# Backing up a MongoDB cluster with mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Can anyone indicate the right way to backup a MongoDB database with `mongodump`?

I have tried:

```
mongodump --host "cluster0-shard-00-00-2djno.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-2djno.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-2djno.mongodb.net:27017" \
  --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username admin \
  --password mypassword -o /tmp
```

When I do that I get:

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Verifying connection to an individual node with both the `ping` and `telnet` commands such that these nodes are valid.

The `mongodump` version is 3.2.13.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on this? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to MongoDB 3.4 was necessary, since the cluster string did not appear to work with 3.2.

Also, based on the blog post for '[importing data](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/atlas-on-day-one-importing-data)', a small tweak to the host parameter seemed necessary, in the form of adding the 'Cluster0-shard-0/' prefix :

```
mongodump --host "Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-2djno.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-2djno.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-2djno.mongodb.net:27017" \
  --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username admin \
  --password mypassword --oplog -o /tmp
```

Edit: updated the response based on @jjussi's feedback. Also, we aren't trying to avoid using the mongo cloud backup, which is more convenient, it is that we just feel better having our own local copy, for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you are connecting to replica set, you must give RS name at start of connection string. You are (here) connecting to replica set, not cluster (even your RS is named "Cluster0-shard-0).  BUT, if you are really taking backup of cluster, you should use file system snapshots or if you want to use mongodump (the hard way), follow [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/) instructions to get consistent backup.

AND you are missing one parameter.. You should add `--oplog` parameter or you cannot restore that RS as "consistent".